# Does Acumatica has support for hierarchyid type?

Tags: sql-server, acumatica

Does Acumatica has support for hierarchyid type which is available in MS SQL 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acumatica does not use that data type.

Branches of hierarchical structures keep a link to their parent nodes, see SiteMap table for an example.